# Importing OpenStreetMap (OSM) to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, openstreetmap, arcgis-editor-osm

I am having some problems with the import of a locally saved osm file into arcmap 10.1. I have installed the Arcgis Editor for osm from here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6a2a3c3cece749558393d4e80241ef51.
I am using windows 10 64 bit. The arcgis 10.1 seems to work fine.
I am trying with Download Extract Symbolize tool and this is the message it gives me.

[image]

There we go this is what happens when i try to load a locally saved OSM file with JOSM editor.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like hinted on by user two seven, you probably installed the 64-bit version of the OSM Editor toolbox, while ***not*** having "ArcGIS 64-bit background geoprocessing" installed. This will not work.

Reminder: you don't need the 64-bit ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap to work with the toolbox on a 64-bit Windows. The 64-bit version is just meant to be used in combination with the "ArcGIS 64-bit background geoprocessing".

ArcGIS 64-bit background geoprocessing is a separate install for ArcGIS. You can either install that, or uninstall the 64-bit version of the ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap toolbox, and install the 32-bit version of the editor toolbox, which should work with your version of ArcGIS having 32-bit geoprocessing.

Comment: I am sure i installed the 32 bit version of the tool , i just uninstalled and reinstalled it again. The problem still persists i get the same message. My arcgis 10.1 is a 32 bit version. I always run it as an administrator so i guess there are no permission problems since my user is an administrator.Any clue of what can cause this error , it is really frustrating.

Comment: Have you tried disabling background geoprocessing altogether? The option is in the Geoprocessing / Geoprocessing Options / Background Processing menu. De-select the "Enable" checkbox there. This will make sure all tools run in the foreground, that is, straight in ArcMap.

Comment: I disabled the background geoprocessing but it still didn´t work. Finally at last i tried to save the features and download the osm at the default geodatabase instead of a connected folder and guess what , it worked !! I will test it further just to be sure.

Comment: Marian, good to hear, but can you tell something more about your set-up. Is ArcGIS running on a "normal" local machine, or is it installed in a VMWare virtualized environment?

Comment: It is a normal desktop machine , pretty modest i would say, CPU Intel E5700 Ram 4GB DDR3 on windows 10 64 bit. A bit slow but for now that is all i got. And i was mistaken on what i said above about the background geoprocessing, in fact disabling it was the key.

Comment: Marian, again good news, but it also means that you actually have the wrong version of the editor installed. Either 1) you have ArcGIS 64-bit background geoprocessing installed (you may not know this, ask you system admin for help if needed), and need to install the 64-bit version of the ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap, or 2) you installed the 64-bit version of the ArcGIS Editor, but only have standard 32-bit background processing.

Comment: I am an individual just trying to experiment a little with arcgis , so i am the system administrator. The arcgis version is 32 bit without geoprocessing since i uninstalled and reinstalled it again i am sure. Running on a 64 bit system and ofcourse the OSM Editor installed is the 32 bit version. I guess my machine is too slow and cant handle the background geoprocessing.Anyways now the problem is solved when i will be ready to upgrade to 10.3 64 bit i will not forget to install the 64 bit backgroung geoprocessing and the 64 bit version of the OSM Editor.Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Are there restrictions on the access of your Windows user profile in your organization? The error message indicates it can't get access to it, probably in an attempt to write out some temporary files.

You may need to ask your Windows system / network administrator.

Alternatively, did you have a second ArcMap session open, possibly pointing to the same datasource / file geodatabase? Close it, to be sure it doesn't put locks on it that may prevent access.

Comment: This is happening even in windows 7 in another pc. Same error same message. Even if i try to load another OSM file with the `Load OSM File´ tool  wich i extracted with JOSM Editor it gives me an error : ERROR 001143 : Background server threw an exception. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Disable background processing in geoprocessing options for the lower error.

Comment: The top error appears to be permission / full disk sort of thing.